# Getting uniqueness on multiple model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are three models:

```
# Table name: activities_people
#
#  activity_id :integer          not null
#  person_id   :integer          not null
#  date        :date             not null
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#
# Table name: activities
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(20)       not null
#  description :text
#  active      :boolean          not null
#  day_of_week :string(20)       not null
#  start_on    :time             not null
#  end_on      :time             not null
```

Third model is people.
Associations:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities_people
  has_many :people, through: :activities_people
end

class ActivitiesPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :activity
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :activities, through: :activities_people
end
```

Issue:
I don't know how to create validation method in ativities_person.rb to protect joining on activities, that overlaps timely.

Example:

person_id:1 join to activity, that will 08.08.2016(date) and last 09:00(start_on) - 10:00(end_on).
 Same person want save to another activity, that will also be 08.08.2016 and last 09:30(start_on) - 10:30(end_on). Now 
validation should throw error that he's save to other activity in same time(time ranges overlap). Validation first should check that dates match, next should check time overlaps of activities.

What I tried:

```
  def check_join_client
    # check if client joined to some activities in same date as current join
    activities_date = person.activities_people.where(date: date)

    if activities_date.any?
      # get start_on and end_on for current activity and date
      get_activities = person.activities.where(id: activities_date.pluck(:activity_id))
      ol_activities = get_activities.where('((start_on <= :start_on AND
                                                    end_on >= :end_on) OR
                                                   (start_on <= :start_on AND
                                                    end_on <= :end_on AND
                                                    end_on >= :start_on) OR
                                                   (start_on >= :start_on AND
                                                    start_on <= :end_on AND
                                                    end_on >= :end_on))',
                                                  start_on: get_activities.pluck(:start_on),
                                                  end_on: get_activities.pluck(:end_on))
    end
  end
```

My method isn't correct. I'm confuse how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your database type, I think with Postgres there's the OVERLAP function which you could use to do such queries.

A resulting query could be like:

```
Activity.where("(start_on, end_on) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", start_on, end_on)
```

Another approach which is a bit DB agnostic, but I've not been able to test is this:

```
Activity.find_by_sql("SELECT e1.* FROM activities e1, activities e2 WHERE(e2.end_on >= e1.start_on AND e2.start_on < e1.start_on)")
```

But the above approach would return an array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation, i.e you can't chain AR methods to it. It's untested, but I think it should work!

**UPDATE**

Validation can now be performed using an approach like this

```
class Activity
  scope :overlapping_activity, ->(activity) { where("(start_on, end_on) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", activity.start_on, activity.end_on) }
  validate :not_overlapping_activity

  def not_overlapping_activity
    if Activity.overlapping_activity(self).any?
      errors.add(:overlapping, "There is an overlapping activity for this period")
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if I was able to help..

Comment: it's nice tip, but not exactly what I want. I still don't have idea how create proper method to get properly uniqueness.

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean by properly uniqueness, but I've added the validation to ensure that overlapping events are not created.

Comment: for activities i have method that check overlaps depends on pool_zone. I want checking person sign in. I cannot join to activities where are overlaps e.g. activity 1 is on pool_zone a activity 2 on b, are on same time and date, and I cannot join to second if I joined to activity 1.

Comment: @oeroluwa. I have problem with your code. It's error: `ERROR:  function pg_catalog.overlaps(time without time zone, time without time zone, unknown, unknown) is not unique`